# Target the child element of a .last()

Tags: jquery

How does one target a specific child element of a .last() element.

Here's what I have currently:

HTML

```
<div class="rules-step"><select class="and_option"></select></div>
<div class="rules-step"><select class="and_option"></select></div>
<div class="rules-step"><select class="and_option"></select></div>
<div class="rules-step"><select class="and_option" style="opacity:0.5"></select></div>
<a class="deletelistitem"></a>
```

JS

```
$(".deletelistitem").on('click', function() {
  $(".rules-step").last().siblings('.and_option').css( "opacity", "1" );
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find()` instead of `.siblings()` as select are child elements of div:

```
 $(".deletelistitem").on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".rules-step").last().find('.and_option').css( "opacity", "1" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children` to get the  **right target**  , like this :-

```
 $(".deletelistitem").on('click', function () {
    $(".rules-step").last().children('.and_option').css("opacity", "1");
 });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h2wLyLLc/1/) :**

Don't use `siblings` . As the **target element** is not the `siblings` of the **last div having rules-step class** . It's the child node of the last `div` .